# ASP.NET MVC ModalState is always invalid for password with lowercase, upper case and special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on ASP.NET MVC application and i have created a fields password with following regex annotations

```
    [Display(Description = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression(@" /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&_/\*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8,128}/", ErrorMessage = "The password can only consist of 1 Capital & three lower case letters, 1 Special Character , 1 number")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Now I have entered password

```
L@hore123
```

My Modal is always invalid. In my modal i have checked that attempted value is

```
L@HORE123
```

dose anyone have idea why mvc is invalidating and converting to upper case? any fix will be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with my RegEx

Replaced

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&_/\*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8,128}/
```

With

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&_/\*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8,128}
```

Worked.

Hope this will help someone else.